# How to Start two application on separate IOLoop on the same port In Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, ioloop

```
import tornado
from tornado import httpserver
from tornado import web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class ServiceHandler1(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "service1 handler"

class ServiceHandler2(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "service2 handler"

def main():
    print "started main"
    application1 = web.Application([
        (r"/app1", ServiceHandler1),
        (r"/app2", ServiceHandler2),
    ])
    http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application1)
    http_server.listen(8080)

    print "start ioloop"
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print "started"
```

I want to start /app1 in one ioloop and /app2 on a different ioloop
so that the calls to these APIs don't block each other

Comment: Err, _what_?  You can't have two processes listen on the same port.  That's not how ports work.  If _something_ is listening on a port, and _something else_ tries to bind it, it should get a PortInUse exception (or whatever the analog is in whatever system / language you're using).

Comment: From the tornado docs:  https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html  "Tornado includes a built-in multi-process mode to start several processes at once. ... This is the easiest way to start multiple processes and have them all share the same port, although it has some limitations." ... ... so it will listen in the main IOLoop, and then divy connections out to child processes, but you don't _actually_ get multiple processes _listening_ on the same port.  What you're trying to do _should never work_. That's not how ports work.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, will update the code and accordingly and reform my question.

Comment: You can bind a Nginx server to a single port which would redirect certain requests to whatever ports you would require.